# Desiarializing particular objects with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a class structure tha have particular implamentations that I need deserialize with Gson.

My class is:

```
Class Foo 
{
  String name;
  Money vlr; //this is my implementation over double values
  Data dt;   //this is my implementation over java.util.Date
 .
 .
 .

}
{"name":"Hello","vlr":1500, "dt":01/01/2015}
```

In my Json, if I pass values to vlr or dt I have the follow error:

```
new Gson().fromJson(jsonTexto, Foo.class);

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

How I can do this? How to determine values do my Money and Data atributes in my Json String? Or, how to inform to Gson to use Money and Data class to parse the values?

Thanks

Comment: `.oO( IT must be the fifth Java/JSON/Gson related question w/i the last 7 days ... :/ )` Please use the search function before posting. _And: There are quotes missing around your date._

Comment: @user1352652 can you show your Money & Data classes

Answer (score 0):

If you check your JSON, for example here

http://jsonlint.com/

You will see that it is not correctly formatted

> "dt":01/01/2015

It's invalid, hence the error you are getting. Try parsing "dt":"01/01/2015"